# Android, Google Maps Android api, setting location and map type

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm new to Android and trying to get my app to open up a new activity on button click which displays a map using Google maps Android api.

I'm able to get a standard map to render on button click without issue, but when I try to add a location and a map type, my app crashes with this error.

"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference"

Here's the xml fragment layout that my Activity is pointing to.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    />
```

Here's my java code.

```
map1 = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();
        if (map1 == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Maps", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            map1.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            final LatLng LOCATION_1 = new LatLng(37.7576171,-122.5776844);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(LOCATION_1)
                .zoom(17)
                .bearing(90)
                .tilt(30)
                .build();
      map1.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

I've done a few hours of research and I'm at a loss. I'm wondering if it's possible that something is missing in my manifest?

Any help would be appreciated.

My manifest in case it's relevant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="...."
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity3">
        </activity>


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="8298000"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCCk5zREDbtWJD-tFru8xmRZow0ocVXIps"/>

    </application>


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change code a little, you are entering MapFragment in xml, you need to enter SupportMapFragment.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>
```

Secondly, according to google map docs, getMap() method is deprecated. Since, it does not always return non-null value. It can be null many times : 
        https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMap()

Use getMapAsync() method, this method has a callback mechanism. It will call back once the map is ready. So, it returns non-null value always.

Complete Code :

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        final LatLng LOCATION_1 = new LatLng(37.7576171,-122.5776844);
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(LOCATION_1)
            .zoom(17)
            .bearing(90)
            .tilt(30)
            .build();
             googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
});
```